# How to auto-populate DDL with the user who is currently logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need the drop down list to take the user who is currently logged in and automatically make that user the selected item in the list when they visit the create page. I will set the DDL to disabled on the razor page so the user can't create for other users.

I've tried a few things but I've had no luck.

```
    // GET: TimeStamps/Create
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "FullName");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: TimeStamps/Create
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,UserId,ClockIn,ClockOut")] TimeStamps timeStamps)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.TimeStamps.Add(timeStamps);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "FullName", timeStamps.UserId);
        return View(timeStamps);
    }
```

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, "User", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("UserId", null, "Select...", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control"})
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserId, (SelectList)ViewBag.MyList, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `DropDownListFor` helper method with a strongly typed view model.

```
public class CreateVm
{
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Users {set;get;}
  public int SelectedUserId {set;get;}
  public DateTime ClockIn {set;get;}
  public DateTimeClockout {set;get;}
}
```

and in your Get action,

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm = new CreateVm();
  vm.Users= db.Users.Select(f=>new SelectListItem { Value=f.Id.ToString(), 
                                                    Text=f.FullName}).ToList();
  vm.SelectedUserId= 1; // Set the value here
  return View(vm);
}
```

I hard coded the value `1` to be selected. Replace that with your current user id (I don't know how you are storing that).

and in your view which is strongly typed to this view model

```
@model CreateVm
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  // Your other fields also goes here
  @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedUserId,Model.Users)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Now in your HttpPost action, you may use the same view model

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateVm model)
{
  var e=new TimeStamp { UserId=model.SelectedUserId, 
                        ClockIn=model.ClockIn, Clockout=model.Clockout };
  db.TimeStamps.Add(e);
  db.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction("Index");

}
```

**One thing to remember is, even if you disable the dropdown, user's can udpate the value of your SELECT element to be anything else. So i strongly suggest you to set the value again in your HttpPost action method before save.**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateVm model)
{
  var e=new TimeStamp { ClockIn=model.ClockIn,Clockout=model.Clockout };
  e.UserId = 1; // Replace here current user id;
  db.TimeStamps.Add(e);
  db.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction("Index");      
}
```